# Convention to prevent accidental call of instance variable

Tags: ruby

Let's say we have class

```
class Evaluator
  attr_reader :response

  def initialize(response)
    @response = response
  end

  def order
    @_order ||= Order.find(response.order_id)
  end
end
```

I'd like to ask about `@_order` which exists only for caching purposes. This convention is  to prevent accidental use of an instance variable (when it is not initialized yet, for example). I'd like to force using `order` instead of `@order`. What do you think about it? Do you know any better way of achieving this goal?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make instance variables inaccessible from subclasses, in Ruby. Instance variables are *protected* (in common programming terms) by default, which means that they are not accessible from the outside of the class, but are accessible from within the class hierarchy.

You can only control the accessibility of methods with the use of `private`, `protected` and `public`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it painfully obvious that one should not use the member, like calling it `@lazy_loaded_order`, or even generalize it like this:

```
def order
  @lazy_members[:order] ||= Order.find(response.order_id)
end
```

This way, it is obvious that anyone trying to use `@lazy_members` will do it on his own risk...